# Map My Fitness TCX to Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert

I've been using the [Map My Fitness App](http://www.mapmyfitness.com/) from under amour for a bit now and I'd definitely recommend it. Where this app falls short is the export of data. It only goes to a Garmin specific TCX format.

Now I don't know a whole lot about this format outside of its XML-ish. I'm weird and love to collect, store, classify and visualize my runs/hikes/kayaks. *I probably spend more time on this then actually exercising :S*.

There doesn't seem to be a native ArcGIS import tool or process for getting TCX into a shapefile or feature class. So I've started decoding it and am in the process of writing a parser that with the help of the [Shapefile.py](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) module will convert the data.

Now it's taking some time as the TCX XML is well funky. Now I figure I'll probably get the parser done in the next few days when I have some spare time, but **has anyone else written any code or built a module or tool within ArcGIS that would accomplish this**?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) applicable?

Comment: TCX to KML http://www.oe-files.de/oefiles/gmaps/tcx_to_kml_html then load in ArcGIS save as shapefile

Comment: As always you ROCK @Mapperz . It gave me a few funky outputs at first, but then got er done. Add it as an answer so I can check mark it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Convert TCX (Training Center XML format by Garmin) to Shapefile**

An Online Converter can get you TCX to Google KML

When you have the converted KML this will be readable in ArcGIS when KML is loaded up in ArcGIS then you can right click and save as shapefile (or file geodatabase).

Tool to convert TCX to KML online is here
http://www.oe-files.de/oefiles/gmaps/tcx_to_kml_html